# How can I create UTC date in PHP which can be parsed in javascript using getUTCFullYear()

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, date-format

I am working with [kimonolabs](http://www.kimonolabs.com/worldcup/explorer) worldcup api.

Now the problem is while filtering with `startTime` field. In the [documentation](http://www.kimonolabs.com/worldcup/docs) the `startTime` field is defined as `UTC DateTime`.

I have generated UTC datetime using PHP like:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

But while running the filtering - the API gives as error saying:

```
Object 2014-06-21T19:03:47Z has no method 'getUTCFullYear'
```

I believe that `getUTCFullYear()` is a javascript function which extracts four digit year value from a date object.

My question is how can I generate a datetime format which will remove the error and give me data?

My API call is like:

```
http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/matches?status=Pre-game&startTime=2014-06-21T19:03:47Z
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: [`getUTCFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear) is a method of a JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Your date format can be used to instantiate one of those just fine, as you can see if you pop open your browser's console and execute `new Date('2014-06-21T19:03:47Z').getUTCFullYear()`.

Comment: This is just a bug on Kimono's end. Note that your example call ([here's one including an API key](http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/matches?status=Pre-game&startTime=2014-06-21T19:03:47Z&apikey=f266838ac6d1ef081e21ffcb8cfdbd51)) returns a *500*, indicating an internal server error, not a 400 for a mistake in your request. The docs on the Match object indicate that the startTime field is of type 'date', and I'd guess they just don't support filtering on fields of that type.

Comment: I've sent them a bug report as a courtesy. Unfortunately, while the issue with the Kimono API is real, the *actual question* you've asked here (about PHP's date functions and JavaScript's `getUTCFullYear` method) doesn't really make any sense. `getUTCFullYear` is a method of `Date` objects themselves. It does *not* parse strings (or do any parsing of any kind) to generate `Date` objects. Talking about creating something which can be 'parsed' by `getUTCFullYear` is thus incoherent. For that reason, I'm voting to close.

Comment: @MarkAmery, On your first point - yes I believe that is a bug from Kimono's end. I also have notified them about that. 


On the second point - may be the problem is in my language! What I meant really was - can I generate a date in PHP which can be accepted as a javascript ``date`` object if I use the value in javascript? If yes -- how?


However, as I have got your support with logic that it is a bug from service end - I am willing to close this question. Can you please give your comment as an answer? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on building this API. Mark is correct, the issue was on our end and not with the request you were making. I've made some updates now so it should be able to handle any valid string that can be passed into the javascript Date constructor.

I'm also not sure what exactly you wanted to use the date for, but it seemed unlikely that you wanted to look up matches by an exact timestamp. I thought it would be useful to add the ability to query on less than/greater than values. For timestamps in particular this should allow you to do make much more practical queries.

Here are some possible queries you can make now:

```
/matches?startTime__lt=2014-06-21T19:03:47Z
/players?birthDate__gt=1990-12-12
/players?goals__gte=2
```

Hopefully this helps resolve the issues you were having with the API!

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. What I was trying to fetch upcoming matches or todays matches. 

However I think your solution works fine for me.

I have called:
```PHP
http://worldcup.kimonolabs.com/api/matches?status=Pre-game&startTime__gt=2014-06-25T10:00:00Z&startTime__lt=2014-06-26T22:00:00Z
```

Thanks for the support. And marking it to be completed.